# Clearing an output after it's printed

Tags: python, python-3.8

Is there any way to clear an output after it's printed, for an example if we write a code for a countdown the printed value is immediately cleared and another value is printed in the same place which the previous output was printed.

```
import time
a = [5,4,3,2,1,0]
for i in a:
    time.sleep(0.2)
    print(i,end="",)
```

Here the output is printed on the same line but is there a way to clear an output to print the next value in the same position which the previous output was like in a loading screen or a countdown (like 'cls' in the command prompt but as a process while the program is still running).

I would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flush the output and print a carriage return character to place the cursor at the beginning of the line:

```
import time
a = [5,4,3,2,1,0]
print()    # start on a new line
for i in a:
    time.sleep(0.2)
    print(i, end="\r", flush=True)
print()
```

Note that this will not clear the line, so you might want to do this too:

```
for i in [500] + a:
    time.sleep(0.2)
    print('\033[K', i, sep='', end="\r", flush=True)
```

Where `\033[K` is the [ANSI escape sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to clear the line.

Comment: Nice job with \033[K. My code was not working for double digits!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. Use \r for end argument of print() call.

```
import time
for x in range(5, -1, -1):
    print(f'\033[KCounting down {x}', end='\r')
    time.sleep(1)
print()
```

The last print() is to move your cursor to next line otherwise the shell will overwrite the last line and \033[K is the ANSI escape sequence to clear the line.